# How do I mark a database in a inconsistent state as resolved in production with Play

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am using Scala Play version 2.3.1 with the following environments

- Development on a Laptop
- Test with a Heroku deployment
- Live with a
  Heroku deployment

I am making a change to the database structure using evolutions. It was a little complicated involving the removal of indexes and the adding of others. This is evolution 5. Test and live are currently on evolution 4.

If I blow away the database on my development machine, the application works as expected. If I deploy to test I get 'Application Error' when I access any web page

In the logs I get:

> play - Run with -DapplyEvolutions.default=true and
>   -DapplyDownEvolutions.default=true if you want to run them automatically, including downs (be careful, especially if your down
>   evolutions drop existing data) Database 'default' needs evolution!
>   Oops, cannot start the server.

I do actually have  -DapplyEvolutions.default=true set, but I don't have the 'downs' enabled (They are destructive and I don't want to execute them) When I go to the database via Sql Squirrel I find the following

- 5 rows
- Each column 'applied_at' has a data in it (including row 5)
- Each column 'state' has the value 'applied' in it

I have investigated the database and evolution 5 has been applied.

So if I was running in development mode, I would probably get the web page 'database default is in an inconsistent state'. I would click the 'Mark it resolved' button, and I could continue

How do I do this when running in 'production mode'?

Comment: Perhaps backup your production database and connect to it via the local app to see what it says? I usually do this when applying large evolutions, otherwise I'll get a boot timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm going to follow it. The test database is a about half a terrabytes. I tried this a couple of days ago, and just had to press the mark resolved button and it all worked. I'm going to give it another go now, and look see if the logs give a better message locally. I don't get a boot timeout: the evolutions have actually been applied, and the new indexes are in place

Comment: How very annoying. It runs fine. No 'your database is in an inconsistent state' or anything. Still, I think I am going to get similar issues in the future, and I'd like to understand how to work with the evolutions when they go wrong. I think being able to 'get the database in the right configuration' and then 'marking it as resolved' gives me a set of tools that will be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I received this answer from the Google Group Play-Framework

> Unfortunately you can not “mark the database as resolved” if you run
>   the application in Prod mode. I think this is a problem in Play, can
>   you please file an issue about that
>   (http://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues)?
>
> To solve your problem, you can either run the application in Dev mode
>   (using `sbt run`) and then click on the button from your web browser,
>   or manually update the play_evolutions table to mark your conflicts as
>   resolved (here is how it is done by Play:
>   https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/EvolutionsApi.scala#L297-L311).

Having raised the issue, I executed the following manually

```
update play_evolutions set state = 'applied' where state = 'applying_up' and id = " + revision
delete from play_evolutions where state = 'applying_down' and id = " + revision
```

This didn't explain all my symptoms: but I could easily of had two issues. For example when I looked at the play_evolution table there were no 'applying_up' or 'applying_down'. However this has certainly 'resolved' this part of the problem, and helped quite a bit with my understanding of what was happening